# Need to substring the last white spaces

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios4, nsstring

I have the string

```
"Avenida Indianopolis                , 1000"
```

and I need get "Avenida Indianopolis, 1000"

How can I do this?

Comment: the &nbsp are spaces.. here I cant write spaces

Comment: I'm confused, you just edited the `&nbsp`'s into your post, are you trying to remove them from an Objective-C string or just regular spaces?

Comment: where you see &nbsp is regular spaces..Stack overflow doesn't accept that I write multiples whitespaces

Comment: can you attach image of your string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to replace everything with two or more spaces with one space:

```
 {2,}
```

Example:

```
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@" {2,}" options:0  error:NULL];

NSMutableString *string = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"Avenida Indianopolis      , 1000"];
[regex replaceMatchesInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length]) withTemplate:@" "];
```

However, in your example this would result in a space before the comma, so you might actually want to replace the spaces with nothing (or run a second pass over the string and clean up the space + comma, depending on how your input strings are formed)

Comment: what if there are 7 spaces?

Comment: @Prateek Then the code will still work? What is your question?

Comment: @illDev Run the example I posted, it strips the spaces from the string and outputs `Avenida Indianopolis , 1000`

Comment: NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@" {2,}" options:0  error:NULL];
        
        NSMutableString *string = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"Avenida Indianopolis      , 1000"];
        [regex replaceMatchesInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length]) withTemplate:@" "];
        
       NSLog(string);

Im getting with more than 1 space..

Comment: @illDev See my comment under the code in case you don't want the comma + space. Your question simply asked to replaces multiple spaces with one space, if that isn't what you want, you have to refine the code a bit. For example you could replaces the template with an empty string to replace the spaces with nothing.

Comment: `NSMutableString *string = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"Rua X      ,177, Mirandópolis"];//have 3 spaces between Rua X and ,`


How do I in this case?

Comment: @illDev It's the same. The regular expression will match everything with more than two spaces and then replace the spaces with whatever you want.

Comment: I need replace with only 1 white space

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
NSString *str = "Avenida Indianopolis &nbsp &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp, 1000";
str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&nbsp" withString:@""];
```

Try this if space is present instead of &nbsp

```
NSString *str = "Avenida Indianopolis    , 1000";
str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"     " withString:@""];
```

Comment: If &nbsp is a string(instead of spaces) then only this function is used.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
NSString *string = @"Avenida Indianopolis &nbsp &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp, 1000";
string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&nbsp" withString:@""];
string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&nbsp " withString:@""];
```

Hope it helps you..

EDIT

```
NSString *string = @"Avenida Indianopolis &nbsp &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp, 1000";
string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"     " withString:@" "];
```

Comment: Because it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Because OP only included the html space code to signify spaces because SO's text field wouldn't allow him to input multiple spaces.

Comment: @JustSid As per question, there are 5 whitespace which need to be replaced by single whitespace, according to which my code is right

Comment: @Prateek Well kinda, there are 7 spaces shown in the post, and this could be faulty because it assumes that there will always be the same number of spaces.

Comment: @0x7fffffff as per question, he said there are 5 whitespace and need one whitespace, according to that code is right, why downvote?

Answer (score 0):

I think the key to this is you need to remove all the spaces before the ','.

For that, use the regular expression @" +,": one or more spaces followed by a comma.

```
NSRegularExpression *re = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@" +," options:0 error:NULL];

NSMutableString *data = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"Avenida Indianopolis      , 1000"];
[re replaceMatchesInString:data options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, data.length) withTemplate:@","];

STAssertEqualObjects(data, @"Avenida Indianopolis, 1000", nil);
```